# Turn on MacBook Air without keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, power

How can I turn on my MacBook Air model A1370 mid 2011 without a keyboard? I need to find the power on pads for the Mac:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found this for you (follow the red arrow)

[image: power on]

and this [information](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/115829/How+to+power+on+without+power+button+on+MacBook+air+late+2010)

or this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOJVqqf0az0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my logic board Is different from what you showed me look good picture I took on my first message my macbook air is of mid 2011 model A1370 please

Comment: OK, the video is for the Model A1370